# Папка assets из отдельного репозитория git

Tags: android, git

Есть проект на android, который подтягивает из папки assets кучу текстовых файлов. Есть необходимость вынести данную папку в отдельный репозиторий git.
Можно ли так сделать - весь проект лежит в одном репозитории, а папка assets в другом? И каким образом их правильно собирать?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Инструменты-Git-Подмодули

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @katso за наводку!

И так что я сделал.

1. Есть отдельный репозиторий с основным проектом.
2. Создал репозиторий, в который положил файлы, которые должны лежать в assets основного проекта.
3. Через git bash выполнил команду

   git submodule add link-to-repo app/src/main/assets

если папка assets уже существовала, то выкинет ошибку `already exists and is not a valid git repo`